# Unable to submit Radio Button response to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm using **name** attribute of a Google Form for submitting my Bootstrap form data to Google Spreadsheet. Every ***text field*** is being submitted successfully, but no response from Radio Buttons.

Actually a radio button response got submitted but it happened only for once, when I added **value="Fron Indus to Oxus English)"** next to the **name** attribute, but I'm unable to figure it out now!

What I did is created similar Google Form with same fields, viewed its source (Ctrl+U) and extracted **name attribute** for each form entity. Then I used that name attribute in my custom built Bootstrap Form. Every response is being submitted successfully, except the Radio Buttons.

I've hosted that Form on Google Drive, so that you could have a look at how it's behaving, view it here:
[**view here: Book Order Form**](https://9c477a2135ea587cca828c0986c764ab70e9203d.googledrive.com/host/0Bz5_0PNA8ZRneTduaHhaLXhRQ3M/index.html)

What you need is here:

**Spreadsheet:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oem-18J6OTBv6C40hGf6CXKIM-N5o9Ri16QA6U21D4c/

Let's say we have these two choices for now, here's the markup:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <input type="radio" name="entry.1896965130" value="From Indus to Oxus (English)">
  <label class="radio-radio-label" >From Indus to Oxus (English)</label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <input type="radio" name="entry.1896965130" value="From Indus to Oxus (Urdu)">
  <label class="radio-radio-label" >From Indus to Oxus (Urdu)</label>
</div>
```

Please review the spreadsheet and figure out how that one response got submitted and why isn't this submitting again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Eventually I found the following code worked:

```
<div class="form-group" name="entry.2000113276">
  <label for="rsvpStatus" class="col-lg-2 control-label">How many?</label>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <label><input type="radio" name="entry.2000113276" value="0">0</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <label><input type="radio" name="entry.2000113276" value="1">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <label><input type="radio" name="entry.2000113276" value="2">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <label><input type="radio" name="entry.2000113276" value="More">More</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to do systematic debugging, but I honestly couldn't figure out what individual component was key to making it work.

Comment: Of course - sorry I don't really have an answer. If it helps, I had the same issue of the radio button working once, then not working. Eventually I standardized to this format, re-served it (on localhost, was using a static site generator called Hugo), then opened it in private browsing/incognito. It worked for all the radio buttons after that.

Comment: How can I apply this to script tag info e.g.       data: {"entry.1012452068":firstname, "entry.1038894874":surname, "entry.1352091133":dob, "entry.1048111489":email, "entry.1786559101":option}, type: "POST", datatype: "xml", statusCode: {0:function() {window.location.replace("thankyou.html");}, 200:function(){window.location.replace("thankyou.html");}}

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while but I had the same situation here and figure out what's causing the issue. So I want to record it here so the others could save time debugging.

To pass the value of a radio button to your google form, the value of the input has to be specified and matches EXACTLY (case sensitive) as the one you set out in your google form.

For example:
You have a radio button for "Female & Male" in your html code and the value is set to "F & M" respectively. But in your linked google form, you has a radio button for "female & male". It will not be passed successful.

To pass the value of your customized html form to google form, you have to alter the value  of that entry in your html form to "female & male".

Therefore, to pass a value successfully to the google form -> sheet, you have to match not only the "name" attribute but also the "value".